# Array index out of bound, why?

Tags: java, arrays

The code is rather simple but I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "States.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);

    try {
        Scanner stream = new Scanner(file); // or use new File();
        while (stream.hasNext()){
            String data = stream.next();
            String[] values = data.split(",");
            System.out.println(values[3] + "***");
        }
        stream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There supposely something wrong on `system.out.println(values[3] - "***")` and I looked but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure the minimum length of `values` is 4?

Comment: Make sure the values array is of length atleast 4.

Comment: The error here occurs because the array does not have an item at the index of 3 in some cases. There might not be enough values delimited by commas according to your split for example ("hello, world, bye") would cause such an error whereas ("hello, world, bye, foo") would not.

Comment: No the minimum lenght of values is random, I just wanted to print the 4 index of value?

Comment: I would suggest you to check the contents of your file "States.csv".  Check the value of System.out.println(values[2] + "***"); and see what happens.

Comment: If you want to print the 4th index char in the string, why are you doing a split on ","? Are you familiar with what split even does?

Answer (score 5):

Because the size of the `array` is probably less that `4` and you are trying to print the `4th` element (index `3`)

Check your `array` length before print:

```
try {
    Scanner stream = new Scanner(file); // or use new File();
    while (stream.hasNext()){
        String data = stream.next();
        String[] values = data.split(",");
        if(values.length>3){
            System.out.println(values[3] + "***");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Desired value is missing in this row");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also like to re-iterate what @RakeshKR said. Try closing your streams in the `finally` block to guarantee that they are closed, even if an exception is caught.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the length of values is less than 4. That's why it is causing exception for values[3]. if you want to print the last value then you can use

```
        System.out.println(values[values.length - 1] + "***");
```

or if you need to print the 4th index then check whether the size of value is less than 4

```
if(values.lenght > 3)
        System.out.println(values[3] + "***");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check values hava a min length of 4.

```
// For printing all splited values
for(String val : data.split(",")){
     System.out.println(val);
}
```

Suggestion:

Close your streams in finally block

**Note** :  The index of array starts from `0` not from `1`

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the data string. The split() method split around the the comma. If you only have one comma in your original string then the values array would only be a length of 2.